# Hyperledger fabric 1.2 capabilities error

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I am trying to use hyperledger fabric sample network with my own chaincode. 
I am using [balance-transfer](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.4/balance-transfer) but my chaincode requires collections config file because It is using private data. I added to sendInstantiateProposal request but, I keep getting the error while instantiating the chaincode;

```
{"success":false,"message":"Failed to instantiate the chaincode. cause:instantiate proposal resulted in an error :: Error: as V1_2 or later capability is not enabled, private channel collections and data are not available"}
```

I added capabilities section to artifacts/channel/configtx.yaml file but error still continue. You can see that file from [this link.](https://gist.github.com/nurulmac11/7452461ad6b846a0ce5e6c944b66041c)

So, how can I solve this error and make this network work with private channels ?

Comment: maybe you are running older version of hyperledger fabric.

Comment: I think version is correct because I set the version by editing runApp.sh and added
 
`export IMAGE_TAG="1.2"`

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when Application and channels are not enabled with the V1.2 or above capabilities.

Solution:

Add Capabilities in configtx.yaml file

```
Capabilities:
    # Channel capabilities apply to both the orderers and the peers and must be
    # supported by both.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        # V1.3 for Channel is a catchall flag for behavior which has been
        # determined to be desired for all orderers and peers running at the v1.3.x
        # level, but which would be incompatible with orderers and peers from
        # prior releases.
        # Prior to enabling V1.3 channel capabilities, ensure that all
        # orderers and peers on a channel are at v1.3.0 or later.
        V1_3: true

    # Orderer capabilities apply only to the orderers, and may be safely
    # used with prior release peers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        # V1.1 for Orderer is a catchall flag for behavior which has been
        # determined to be desired for all orderers running at the v1.1.x
        # level, but which would be incompatible with orderers from prior releases.
        # Prior to enabling V1.1 orderer capabilities, ensure that all
        # orderers on a channel are at v1.1.0 or later.
        V1_1: true

    # Application capabilities apply only to the peer network, and may be safely
    # used with prior release orderers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        # V1.3 for Application enables the new non-backwards compatible
        # features and fixes of fabric v1.3.
        V1_3: true
        V1_2: false
        V1_1: false
```

And then apply them in Profile section

```
ThreeOrgsOrdererGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ChannelCapabilities
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                    - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
                    - *Org2
                    - *Org3

    ThreeOrgsChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
                - *Org3
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

Refer [fabric-samples/first-network configtx.yaml](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/first-network/configtx.yaml) file for more details.